# Mocking Gtk# controls for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mono, moq, gtk#

## Edit : [Fixed the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137776/4995329)

### My problem (TL;DR)

I am trying to test my `Gtk#` control wrapper implementation, but when I try to create my object using a mock of `Gtk.Button` as a parameter, I get a

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method 'MyNameSpace.GUI.GTKSharp.GtkSharpButton..ctor' not found.
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
    at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /build/mono/src/mono-4.6.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

#### The test code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class GtkSharpButtonTests
{
    private Mock<Gtk.Button> _buttonMock;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void BeforeAllSetUp()
    {
        _buttonMock = new Mock<Gtk.Button>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void My_Test()
    {
        var called = false;            
        // ---> System.MissingMethodException
        var button = new GtkSharpButton(_buttonMock.Object);

        // .... rest of the test           
    }
}
```

My guess is that when it tries to create the `GtkSharpButton` (my implementation) it creates it with a `Castle proxy object`, but it does not find a `GtkSharpButton` constructor which expects this type.

It also might be a problem with mocking a concrete class, maybe I am doing this wrong.

I have tested the other layers with the same technique, but the others rely on interface, so easier to mock.

Packages used:

- `Moq v4.5.23`
- `NUnit v2.6.4`
- `Castle.Core v3.3.3`
- `gtk-sharp v3.0.0` (from `gtk-sharp-3.0 v2.99.3`)
- `glib-sharp v3.0.0` (from `gtk-sharp-3.0 v2.99.3`)
- `atk-sharp v3.0.0` (from `gtk-sharp-3.0 v2.99.3`)

I am on linux using `mono v4.6.1.3` in `Monodevelop v5.10.1`. But this also happens with the `nunit-console v2.4.8`.

### More information about what I am doing

I am currently creating a `C#` app and I want to abstract the `View` layer.

To do so when I create my `Controller` I pass a  view interface (ex. `IMainWindowView`).

This way I can mix and match different implementations:

```
IMainWindowView view = new GtkSharpMainWindowView();
IMainWindowView view = new WPFMainWindowView();

var mainWindowController = new MainWindowController(view);
```

Example of IMainWindowView:

```
public interface IMainWindowView
{
    IButton ExampleButtonName { get; }

    IButton ExampleButtonName2 { get; }

    // ....
}
```

### Code behind these

#### Interfaces:

```
public interface IControl
{
    string Tooltip { get; set; }
}

public interface IButton : IControl
{
    event ButtonClickEventHandler Triggered;

    void Trigger();
}
```

#### Wrapper implementations:

```
public abstract class GtkSharpControl : IControl
{
    protected Widget BaseWidget { get; private set; }

    public string Tooltip
    {
        get { return BaseWidget.TooltipText; }
        set { BaseWidget.TooltipText = value; }
    }

    protected GtkSharpControl(Widget widget)
    {
        if (widget == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(widget));

        BaseWidget = widget;
    }
}

public class GtkSharpButton : GtkSharpControl, IButton
{
    public event ButtonClickEventHandler Triggered;

    protected Button BaseWidget
    {
        get { return base.BaseWidget as Button; }
    }

    public GtkSharpButton(Button button)
        : base(button)
    {
        BaseWidget.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Triggered != null)
            Triggered(this, new ButtonEventArgs());
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        BaseWidget.Click();
    }
}
```

This implementation is currently working well, but I can't currently test the GtkSharp controls implementation layer.

If you need more information, ask.

Comment: what linux? (what distro and version?) how did you install mono? how did you install gtk-sharp?

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux (Kernel version: 4.7.6-1-ARCH). I installed mono using pacman. 

As for gtk-sharp I just realised it was installed when I installed monogame-bin (using pacman). I didn't really think about that when I added the reference in Monodevelop (for a non-monogame project). I'll try getting the gtk-sharp3 lib using nuget instead and see if that makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: It seems I was using gtk-sharp3 (v2.99.3)  in the test project and gtk-sharp2 (v2.12.29) in the actual implementation project. It seems to work better now. Will do a real update when I have more answers.

Comment: gtk-sharp is not provided in nuget; someone uploaded a library there called like that but is not an official maintainer

Comment: Yeah I just saw that, for now I am going to use the one from my package manager, but I would like a more portable version of the application. Either by distributing the DLLs myself (which I don't like since it duplicates an already available library) or some other way, but that's another problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

It was simply a problem of using different library versions. I was not using the same `gtk-sharp` library version for my tests and implementation.

The Code project was using `gtk-sharp2` (v2.12.29)

The Test project was using `gtk-sharp3` (v2.99.3)

So when it created a mock, it created a `gtk-sharp3` button mock, but my class constructor was expecting a `gtk-sharp2` button, so it failed.

Thanks knocte [for helping me figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114007/mocking-gtk-controls-for-unit-tests#comment-67530135) by asking how I installed my `gtk-sharp` lib.